# Embed Word 2013 inside C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-automation

I need to access word add-ins and sql database simultaneously. So embedding word inside C# winform is the only option. But Office above 2007 does not allow us to open word in C# winform web browser anymore. I am at total loss.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have office 2013 installed. I have tried to open a word 97-2003 file (Dragged into the web browser in my C#  winform). But it stills open in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in a nice article by Bradley Smith
http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79

Is a nice guide and solution for your word files. Because you need to set the document to allowed to be a web view-able document. See the url for the code additions.

Regards,

Martijn

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the preview handler do not allow us to edit the word document

Comment: @CodeCafe, could you rephrase your question then. Because for the question you have at the moment this is the solution.

Comment: Because I need to access a plugin ribbons in MS word, but I after reading, I found that it is not possible cannot access the ribbons in word.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article anyway